# Opening the file in Read only mode in Eclipse editor

Tags: editor, eclipse-rcp, xtext

Actually I need to open the File in the Editor as Read-only Mode. I was using

```java
IDE.openEditor(IworkbenchPage, Ifile, true);
```

To open the Editor.I am not aware how to open the file in Read-only mode.can any one have any suggestions please help me.
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

It should work with

```
IDE.openEditor(workbenchPage, new XtextReadonlyEditorInput(file), true)
```

Comment: I followed the same thing what u suggested.but I am getting the Exception stating java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.xtext.ui.editor.XtextReadonlyEditorInput cannot be cast to org.eclipse.ui.part.FileEditorInput.